# The distance of hyperbola to a point

Tags: geometry

Let the hyperbola equation is
$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
I want to know the distance of the hyperbola curve to any point. Since there are symmetrical branches of hyperbola, I don't know how to derive the equation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Compute the distance from the point to each of the branches. Then the distance of the point to the hyperbola will be the smallest of those two numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperbola: $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y2}{b^2} = 1$

Say you have a point $P (h,k)$ which is not on the hyperbola and you want to find its minimum distance to the hyperbola curve.

The square of distance of any point $(x,y)$ on the hyperbola to point $P$ can be written as

$d^2 = (x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2$ ...(i)

Now from the equation of hyperbola,

$\displaystyle y = \pm \frac{b}{a} \sqrt{x^2-a^2}$

Plugging this in $(i)$,

$d^2 = f(x) = (x-h)^2 + (\pm \frac{b}{a} \sqrt{x^2-a^2} - k)^2$

Now we take derivative of this for both plus and minus values of $y$, equate to zero to find critical points and check which point minimizes the square of distance $f(x)$.

$\displaystyle f'(x) = 0 = (x-h) +  \frac{b^2}{a^2} x \mp \frac{b}{a} \frac{kx}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}$

I hope you can take it from here based on the given values.

Comment: If we want to make it a function, should we just take half the branch?

Comment: You are doing this in a program?

Comment: For the given hyperbola, there are two branches, one left of $x-$axis and one to the right. The way I have set it up, it will find critical points on both branches but $\mp$ that you see in $f'(x)$ is for minus and plus values of $y$ for same $x$. So yes you can set up once for plus and once for minus. You can in fact pass sign as a parameter in your function. Once you get $x$, you can plug into hyperbola equation to find both $y$ values and check which  distance is min.